# Assistance with sum for multiple separate rows using multiple criteria please

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to come up with a way to sum the hours by client for a horizontal table that will include multiple clients and employees.

The clients can change as a variable so ideally need to use the Hrs Worked criteria and the client to search through the table and add up the hours.

**Simplified table**

[image: table simplified here]

Tried my knowledge of sumifs and sumproduct combo's but no luck. Excel 365.

Appreciate any help - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls. try this formula in C10 and copy down.

`=LET(rng,C$2:I$5,client1,B10,SUM(IF(TOROW(CHOOSEROWS(rng,SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(rng)/2,1,2)))=client1,TOROW(CHOOSEROWS(rng,SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(rng)/2,2,2))),0)))`

Adjust `rng` to the actual size of the client/Has worked data range. `client1` to the  first name cell of the result table.

Comment: Hey mate, truly grateful. This works. My actual dataset is much larger than this and features more rows in between but I think I can adapt this to it.

Comment: One thing I'm trying to understand is where you divided the number of rows by 2, what was the reasoning for that?

Comment: To separate the Client rows and the Has Worked rows. In the first search for the name and the other returns only the worked hours.

Comment: Thank you! worked it out, the sequence array needs to match the number of steps to look up the correct rows.

Comment: Exactly this is the reason.

Comment: =SUMIF($C$2:$I$4,C10,$C$3:$I$5)  also worked but is less customisable. I found your answer more suited to my more complex dataset